# проблема с файлами php

Tags: php, xampp

у меня 2 рабочих компа, один на Windows другой на МакОс, на винде использую OpenServer, на мак использую xampp.
Столкнулся с проблемой, что один и тот же проект запускается корректно в OpenServer, но в xampp выдает ошибку. 
Мне нужно что бы все работало в xampp, помогите пожалуйста.

Ошибка которая выдается:

Warning: require_once(/opt/lampp/htdocs/project10TEST/www/../src/MyProject\Controllers\MainController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project10TEST/www/index.php on line 4

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/project10TEST/www/../src/MyProject\Controllers\MainController.php' (include_path='.:/php/includes') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project10TEST/www/index.php on line 4

Код, в котором вроде как есть ошибка (в OpenServer почему-то нет ошибки)

```
spl_autoload_register(function (string $className) {
    require_once __DIR__ .'/../src/' . $className . '.php';
});
```

Версия PHP одна и та же, не помню точно какая, 7+.

Все файлы присутствуют

Я могу предположить что проблема либо в настройках xampp, но не знаю как это решить.
Заранее спасибо за ответы

Comment: Зачем тулите `..` когда используете полный путь до корня сайта `__DIR__`.

Comment: @testoverflow Ошибка указывает на отсутствие файла или директории, и невозможности открыть файл, указанных в require. Я как-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой на своём мак. В моём случае помогло использование абсолютного пути, вместо относительно. На подобие `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.  Так же надо убедиться, что, соответственно есть пара на данную директорию.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ваша функция spl_autoload_register не учитывает того, что у класса может быть неймспейс.

Вот посмотрите путь к файлу, который скрипт пытается включить

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/project10TEST/www/../src/MyProject\Controllers\MainController.php

MyProject\Controllers\ - это же явный неймспейс.
```

И думаю, обратные слэши и вызывают ошибку: в МакОС они не язляются делимитерами в пути к файлу. И ищется что-то вроде

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/project10TEST/www/../src/MyProjectControllersMainController.php
```

Comment: Для разделителей, нужно использовать `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. так -же как и для переносов `PHP_EOL`, чтобы впредь такой гемор не встречать с переходами на разные системы.